# ldap_add no such object (32) matched dn dc=domain dc=com

Tags: linux, redhat, ldap, openldap

When im trying to import users to LDAP using this command:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" -W -f  /etc/openldap/root.ldif
```

I have this error:

```
ldap_add no such object (32) 
          matched dn dc=domain,dc=com
```

Let me show you the files:

**/etc/openldap/domain.ldif**

```
dn: dc=domain,dc=com
dc: domain
description: LDAP Admin
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: rootobject 

dn: ou=People, dc=domain,dc=com
ou: People
description: Users of adminmart
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

**/etc/openldap/root.ldif**

```
dn: uid=root,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
uid: root
cn: Manager
objectClass: account
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is your base DN actually dc=domain,dc=com? Check `ldapsearch -hlocalhost -x -sbase | grep '^dn:'` or the configuration on your LDAP server. For OpenLDAP, it'll be the "suffix" line in slapd.conf.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend putting root in LDAP. How will you log on to a machine when it can't reach the LDAP server?

Comment: @IsaacFreeman The command not return anything, and the suffix is "suffix: "dc=domain,dc=com"

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem doing the same command:

```
No such object (32)
matched DN: dc=example,dc=com
```

I checked the LDIF file and all my OUs from LDAP and I was trying to add an entry to an OU that does not exist.

**I solved changing the OU on ldif file for one that exist.** And all worked fine.

Comment: This is a good answer. Perhaps including an example on how to add a new OU to LDAP would improve the answer, as I had to go to the Google machine to find an example of adding an OU to LDAP.

Comment: If you want, you can add the information in order to add a new OU and I will approve it.

Comment: This can help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535082/28279

Answer (score 2):

i had same problem and was pulling my hair out over it, then added new OU to my ldif, like this:

```
dn: ou=(what your error says that is missing),o=(company name),dc=(company name),dc=country
objectclass: (class type)
objectclass: top
ou: people
```

just replace info in ()'s matching to yours and it should work!